# How can I get all models filtering by tag name in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Basically I want to get a list of Post models, filtering them by the Tag objects contained in Post.tags

Here's my dumbed-down code:

```
def post_list(request, **kwargs):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('name')
    posts.filter(tags__name__contains=kwargs["sort_val"], published=True)
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', {"posts": posts})
```

In my models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

This then gives me the error:
**Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: content, id, tags, title**

Comment: Are you sure  posts = Post.objects.order_by('name') is working, it looks like its the order by 'name' thats the problem?

Comment: Argh that was the problem! Darn copy and paste... Thanks, James.